# Problems with PSTricks and Floating Point

Tags: pstricks

When creating a picture with pstricks I want to do some simple calculations fot proper positioning. Therefore I use the "fp"-Package.
It turns out that the usage of the \FPeval-command seems to shift the whole pspicture-coordinatesystem a bit to the right. Every time an \FPeval is executed.
Has anyone suggestions to work around this phenomenon?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot}

\begin{document}

 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1, -1)(2, 1)

      \cnode(1, 0){0pt}{itemID B}%

      \FPeval\itemPosx{10}

      \cnode(1, 0){0pt}{itemID B}%

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `%` at the end of `\FPeval`

```
\FPeval\itemPosx{10}%
```

There is a trailing space without it. PSTricks macros itself kill all glue but not other macros. What kind of calculations do you need? You have the possibility of PS coordinates like `(! whatever do you need)` which can calculate any coordinates.